# Reversing polarity automatically

Tags: microcontroller

I'm looking for a circuit to extend my 24v linear actuator all the way out and then all the way back in when I push a button. I've tried mechanical switches but I want the cycle to be automatic.

Comment: Use the limit switches that latch, or use limit switches to control latching relays (or regular relays wired to latch electrically).

Comment: There's no need to include your email address unless you're trying to receive more spam.

Comment: Perhaps more crude-but-effective would be to detect an over current condition when the actuator stalls at the end stop; this may or may not be what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a circuit requiring only two standard electromagnetic relays.

[image]

Comment: It can be done with one DPDT relay and two SPDT limit switches if the relay coil and the motor can share the same DC power source.

Comment: @AnalogKid, Yes, but I dropped my version of that, to avoid a retraction without a command, on resumption after a power failure.